# Is there a way to replace an already defined preprocessor identifier?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ios, ipad

I have a library that has several options defined as this:

```
#define shouldShowToolbar YES
#define shouldAlignToLeft YES
etc..
```

and I'm looking for a way to actually replace those from outside (without modifying the library, because the future updates will break it). Is it possible, or am I doomed to change the library source code (which I do have) every time an update comes out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `#undef`

```
#include "library_header.h"    /* Which defines the macro.  */

#undef shouldShowToolbar       /* You undef it.  */
#define shouldShowToolbar NO   /* If you want, you can redefine it.  */
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Undefining-and-Redefining-Macros.html

Comment: +1 for this suggestion, as I think it's a better approach than just redefining the values in a file that is processed after the first file. undef/define pairing allows someone else reading your code to see that you intended on the redefinition and didn't do it by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a particular macro to take effect for a section of code and you know that macro name too, you can use

```
 #undef shouldShowToolbar 

/* Your code */

 #define shouldShowToolbar
```

This wont totally undef the macro, cos you never know which part of your code might actually want it

Answer (score 1):

These are values that are hardcoded at compile time.  If you compile the library with your project then you should be able to redefine them in a file that compiles later in the compile list, I think there is a special keyword for it.  Otherwise it is like saying I want to replace YES in the library.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, preprocessor directives executes before compilation. So after that, there's no chance to change something.